# Create a binary tree, code review request

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Ok, code reviewers, I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or more simple. ( Generics would be added a bit later).

```
public class CreateABinaryTree {
    private TreeNode root;

    public CreateABinaryTree() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binary tree in order of elements in an array.
     * After the number of nodes in the level have maxed, the next 
     * element in the array would be a child of leftmost node.
     * 
     * http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/least-common-ancestor-for-binary-search-tree/31394?noredirect=1#comment51044_31394
     */
    public CreateABinaryTree(List<Integer> items) {
        this();
        create(items);
    }

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        int element;
        TreeNode right;

        TreeNode(TreeNode left, int element, TreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.element = element;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    private void create (List<Integer> items) {   
        root = new TreeNode(null, items.get(0), null);

        final Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode(null, items.get(left), null);
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode(null, items.get(right), null);
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only see one really questionable thing in your code.  Why do you call `this()` in your constructor?  Your parameter-less constructor does absolutely nothing, so this line is irrelevant.  If anything, I would actually even remove that constructor entirely so that your API can only be used with your meaningful and useful one.

Also, as a side note, the following line opens you up to a `NullPointerException` since you never check to see if `items` is `null` or if it has any elements.

```
root = new TreeNode(null, items.get(0), null);
```

Comment: I agree with your point, in this code i should take off the parameterless constructor. But to answer both your concerns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082841/to-null-check-or-not-to-do-a-null-check/19082905?noredirect=1#19082905 - should answer why null ptr check was not done. Plz correct me if i am still wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081965/whats-the-use-of-this-in-linkedlist-java/19082264?noredirect=1#19082264 - should answer why this() is included.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I don't get what you mean by the answer you linked.  It seems to *support* performing a null check of the parameter before using it.  "What I would do in this case, would either check at the beginning if the param is null, and then return false (so it doesn't break the runtime flow - Objective-C style), OR assertIsNotNull at the beginning of the method, and specify it in the javadoc (e.g. "the thing must not be null, yo")."

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Yeah, I get why you would have `this()` if the parameter-less constructor actually *did* anything. :)  It just doesn't, and so it's pointless.  That's all.