# Inorder traversal of a tree without recursion or stack

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Please review the code for code cleanup, smart optimizations and best practices. Also verify my complexity: \$O(n^2)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of nodes.

```
/**
 * This class traverses the tree and returns in-order representation.
 * This class does not recursion and does not use stack.
 * This code is threadsafe.
 */
public final class TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<T> {

    private TreeNode<T> root;

     /**
     * Constructs a binary tree in order of elements in an array.
     * The input list is treated as  BFS representation of the list.
     * Note that it is the clients reponsibility to not modify input list in objects lifetime.
     * 
     * http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/least-common-ancestor-for-binary-search-tree/31394?noredirect=1#comment51044_31394
     */
    public TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack(List<T> items) {
        create(items);
    }


    /**
     * Idea of inner class is supported by linked list and another code found here:
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262308/how-do-implement-a-breadth-first-traversal
     * 
     * @author SERVICE-NOW\ameya.patil
     */
    private static class TreeNode<T> {
        TreeNode<T> left;
        T item;
        TreeNode<T> right;

        TreeNode(TreeNode<T> left, T item, TreeNode<T> right) {
            this.left = left;   
            this.item = item;
            this.right = right;
        }
    } 

    private void create (List<T> items) {        
        root = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(0), null);

        final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();   
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;  

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(left), null);
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode<T>(null, items.get(right), null);
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private TreeNode<T> getInorderSuccessor(TreeNode<T> node) {
        assert node != null;

        TreeNode<T> inorderSuccessorCandidate = node.left;
        while (inorderSuccessorCandidate.right != null && inorderSuccessorCandidate.right != node) {
            inorderSuccessorCandidate = inorderSuccessorCandidate.right;
        }
        return inorderSuccessorCandidate;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the list containing items in inorder form.
     * 
     * @returns the list of items in inorder.
     */
    public List<T> inorderTraversal () {
        final List<T> nodes = new ArrayList<T>();
        TreeNode<T> node = root;

        while (node != null) { 

            if (node.left == null) {
                nodes.add(node.item);
                node = node.right;
                continue;
            } 

            final TreeNode<T> inorderSuccessor = getInorderSuccessor(node);

            if (inorderSuccessor.right == null) {
                inorderSuccessor.right = node;
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                inorderSuccessor.right = null;
                nodes.add(node.item);
                node = node.right;
            }
        }

        return nodes; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
          /**
         *         1
         *       2   3  
         *     4  n  n 7
         */
       Integer[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, 7};
       List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for (Integer i : arr1) {
           list1.add(i);
       }
       TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer> traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack1 = new TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer>(list1);
       System.out.print("Expected: 4 2 1 3 7, Actual: ");
       for (Integer i : traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack1.inorderTraversal()) {
           System.out.print(i + " ");
       }

       System.out.println("\n--------------------------------"); 

       /**
        *       1
        *     2   3
        *   4  n 6  n 
        */
       Integer[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6};
       List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for (Integer i : arr2) {
           list2.add(i);
       }
       TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer> traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack2 = new TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer>(list2);
       System.out.print("Expected: 4 2 1 6 3, Actual: ");
       for (Integer i : traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack2.inorderTraversal()) {
           System.out.print(i + " ");
       }

       System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");

       /**
        *                         1
        *              /                   \
        *           null                     2
        *         /   \                    /    \
        *     null     null            null       3
        *   /    \      /  \         /   \       /  \
        *  null  null null  null  null   null  null  4
        *   
        */
       Integer[] arr3 = {1, null, 2, null, null, null, 3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 4};
       List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for (Integer i : arr3) {
           list3.add(i);
       }
       TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer> traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack3 = new TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer>(list3);
       System.out.print("Expected: 1 2 3 4, Actual: ");
       for (Integer i : traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack3.inorderTraversal()) {
           System.out.print(i + " ");
       }

       System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");

       /**
        *                 4
        *             /     \ 
        *          2          null
        *       /   \        /    \
        *      1    null  null    null
        */
       Integer[] arr4 =  {4, 2, null, 1, null};
       List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for (Integer i : arr4) {
           list4.add(i);
       }
       TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer> traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack4 = new TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack<Integer>(list4);
       System.out.print("Expected: 1 2 4, Actual: ");
       for (Integer i : traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack4.inorderTraversal()) {
           System.out.print(i + " ");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: there would be no need to unbalance the tree if you have a parent pointer in TreeNode

Comment: Modifying a node with `inorderSuccessor.right = node;` during `inorderTraversal()`, making the data structure not a tree, feels like such a dirty hack, even if you undo it later.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few comments on your code and algorithm.

First, I don't understand why you cannot use recursion or a stack. You have not elaborated on this. If it is because this is a learning exercise then perhaps I can understand, but it is a poor example of any normal data-structure manipulation...

If this is a real application then I would have to question the whole thing.... Essentially you are taking a list of Data, and converting it in to a List of data.... there is no apparent manipulation of the data at all (at least from the end-user perspective).

I simply do not see much value in this code.

Still, assuming I am missing something important, what about the actual code? Unfortunately recommending changes while not using a stack or recursion is very challenging.... it's like you have been told to screw two pieces of wood together, but you are not allowed to use a screwdriver.... Ratchet-freak's comment/suggestion to add the parent-node is the right solution... and that fixes a lot, but, without that, there is nothing I feel happy recommending other than some big-picture structural items....

Your class is being treated as the source-data for a loop:

```
for (Integer i : traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack4.inorderTraversal()) {
    ....
}
```

This implies that your class should be [`java.lang.Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and it is not. If you used this then you can simply:

```
for (Integer i : traversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack4) {
    ....
}
```

As for the data structure, since the code is a 'decorator' for an input list, you should just add the parent-node pointer and be done with it. It is something you know in your `create` method so there is no extra work. Alternatively, just use **stack**, or use **recursion**.

As for the complexity of the algorithm, it is only *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* if your input List is an ArrayList or some other *O(1)* access list. If the input is a LinkedList itself, then your complexity jumps to *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*. You should find an *O(1)* way to step through the List in your `create()` method, probably using an Iterator instead of indexed `get(...)` lookups. An Iterator over the input is the safest way to do it, but, if you have no choice then in the `create()` method you should check to see whether the List implements [`java.util.RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html), and if it does not, then you should copy the input in to an ArrayList, and index-get off the arraylist....

```
if (! (items instanceof RandomAccess)) {
    items = new ArrayList<>(items);
}
```

This turns what would be an *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* back to one which scales with *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A minor bug: You get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for an empty list in `TraversalWithoutRecursionWithoutStack.create(List<T> items)`. You don't have a comment stating you need to input a list containing at least something. Consider returning `IllegalArgumentException` and adding a comment.